# Callback for picture taking action

Tags: sony-camera-api

I can fire a picture taking command to the HX90V camera through my phone app. However, if I physically press the shutter button on the camera to take a picture, my app will not know it. I think PlayMemory app can handle this situation. I just do not know how it does it. Is there a callback function that can send an event to my phone when the shutter is pressed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out from their Android sample. The app. uses the getEvent() to poll constantly in a background thread. It is not an efficient way, but it is the only way given the WiFi-Direct nature of the beast.